# (Big) Category O for rational Cherednik algebras

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, sg.symplectic-geometry

Let $H_{c}$, for simplicity, be the rational Cherednik algebra with parameter $t=1$, with triangular strucuture $\mathbb{C}[h] \otimes \mathbb{C} W \otimes \mathbb{C}[h^*]$,  and $(W,h)$ the defining complex representation.

Consider the full subcategory category **$O_c$** of finitely generated $H_c$-modules $M$ such that $h \subset \mathbb{C}[h^*]$ acts locally finitely on $M$. (cf. Gordon, section 5.3 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/0712.1568.pdf)

We have **$O_c$**=$\bigoplus_{\lambda \in h^*/W} \mathcal{O}_c(\lambda)$, where $\mathcal{O}_c(\lambda)$ is the full subcategory of **$O_c$**, consisting of modules $M$ where each $P \in \mathbb{C}[h^*]^W$ is such that $P-P(\lambda)$ acts locally nilpotently. $\mathcal{O}_c(0)$ is the usual category $\mathcal{O}_c$ considered by a number of people.

$\mathcal{O}_c$ is quite well understood: it is a highest weight category in the sense of Cline-Parshall-Scott; we have analogues of Verma modules of Lie theory, BGG reciprocity, KZ-functor, etc (cf. Guay *Projective modules in the category O for the Cherednik algebra*; Ginzburg et al. *On the category O for rational Cherednik algebras*).

**Question** What is the current understanding of the bigger category **$O_c$**?

Works that discuss this bigger category that I know of are the aforementioned work of Ginzburg et al., and also to a certain extent Ginzburg, *On primitive ideals*, and  Bezrukavnikov and Etingof, *Parabolic induction and restriction functors for rational Cherednik algebras*.

References or any discussion you might have on this topic would be greatly appreciated.

I finish with:

**Small question** If $\mathcal{O}_c(0)$ is a semisimple abelian category, is also $\mathcal{O}_c(\lambda)$ a semisimple category for every $\lambda$ as well?